# Second develop branch in git

Tags: git

There are 2 main branches in my git repo: `master` and `develop`. `develop` goes ahead master.  I need to provide some changes and logically it is good to branch from `develop`. But not all the changes of `develop` should be merged into `master` after I finished. How do I do something like that?

```
                       today
                         |
master ------------------------------------------
         |                             ↑
         |                             |
 develop -------------------------     |
               |      |  |             |
               |      ↓  ↓             |
      develop2 --------------------------
```

Comment: I will use cherrypick if do not find anything better. Still hope for something more elegant.

Comment: Sounds like a hotfix branch that takes some changes from develop

Comment: Why would you want things in master but not develop...?

Comment: I can update both master and develop at the same time. Just did not draw this in the scheme.

Comment: @sevenseacat: I think you misunderstand the question. He wants features in develop to be in master but not all of them.

Comment: The more I think about it the more I think what you're thinking of doing is correct. Branch out a develop2 branch but name it something meaningful like "emergency new feature deployment". Then cherrypick stuff from develop into it. When you merge with master it will give you a good history of where and why the code came from.

Comment: oh I see. Yes you're correct, I misinterpreted.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to plan you releases
For example like in [git-flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) or [github-flow](http://scottchacon.com/2011/08/31/github-flow.html).

If you realy need a part of develop in your master branch you should do something like this

```
git branch dev2 HASH_IN_DEV
git checkout master
git merge dev2
```

or in case you are using git-flow you should consider your changes like hotfix:

```
git checkout -b hotfix master
git cherry-pick HASHES
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff hotfix
git checkout develop
git merge --no-ff hotfix
```

Comment: Looks like cherry-picking is the only way. Sad, I hoped to avoid this.

Comment: cherry-picking is not bad if you remember to merge you history to provide meta-info about it

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [feature branches](https://www.atlassian.com/git/workflows#!workflow-feature-branch)?

Each feature branch addresses only a specific issue, and can be merged back to `master` once it is complete. The `develop` branch contains all feature branches, even "incomplete" ones, plus potential extra changes for which you don't want to create a feature branch. You can always cherry-pick commits from `develop` into a new branch from `master` to create a new feature branch.

Once in a while you might want to recreate the `develop` branch from scratch. Also, it's always possible to "update" a feature branch to the current `master` by merging (not rebasing!) from `master`.

Comment: I use feature branches. But in this case the changes from develop which I need in develop 2 already done without them. This is what I was given and cannot change.

Comment: @VarvaraStepanova: Why don't you cherry-pick these changes in `develop` into a new feature branch and merge this into `develop2`?